# Why [App Actions Test Tool] not support shortcuts xml file?

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I had created App Actions using the Android Shortcuts framework:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started

shortcuts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <capability android:name="custom.actions.intent.PLUS_DAYS"
        queryPatterns="@array/PlusQueries">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.noen.maihue.datetimeplus"
            android:targetClass="com.noen.maihue.datetimeplus.MainActivity">
            <parameter
                android:name="day_number"
                android:key="day_number"/>
        </intent>
    </capability>
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="Plus_Days"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/PlusDayShort">
        <capability-binding android:key="custom.actions.intent.PLUS_DAYS">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="day_number"
                android:value="@string/day_number"/>
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>
    <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
        </activity>
```

But if I create a Preview to test, it occur error:

```
    App Actions Test Tool v3.5.5
    No Android Module with actions file reference found. You need one Android Module with an actions file reference.
    Create Actions.xml
```

Why App Actions Test Tool not support shortcuts xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do install another Android Studio plugin "Google Assistant", this plugin also contains an "app actions test tool"